Is it legal to partially move constraints between a constrained optimization problem and an associated Lagrangian problem?
Usually, for a constrained optimization problem such as
\begin{align*}
\max_{x_1,\ x_2}\ &f(x_1,\ x_2) \\
\text{s.t. } &g(x_1,\ x_2) \leq a \\
&h(x_1,\ x_2) \geq b,
\end{align*} the Lagrangian would "eat the constraints" in the form of$$L(x_1,\ x_2,\ \lambda_1,\ \lambda_2) = f(x_1,\ x_2) - \lambda_1(g(x_1,\ x_2) - a) - \lambda_2(h(x_1,\ x_2) - b)$$Then one might set out to maximize the Lagrangian instead.  Is it legal to move only some of the constraints between a constrained optimization problem and an associated Lagrangian problem at will (even if the convention may or may not be to call the result the Lagrangian)?  For example, could one write \begin{align*}
\max_{x_1,\ x_2}\ &f(x_1,\ x_2) - \lambda_2(h(x_1,\ x_2) - b) \\
\text{s.t. } &g(x_1,\ x_2) \leq a
\end{align*}as an equivalent problem?

Yes, this is frequently done, especially in situations where it's easy to optimize over the remaining constraints.
